# CSS Overflow: Visible not working on iOS Chrome & Safari

Tags: css

The problem I'm having is that on Desktop and Android, the Instagram icon looks fine, `overflow: visible` works. However, on iOS it's a different story, `overflow: visible` doesn't work.

HTML for the Instagram icon:

```
{% if settings.social_instagram_link != blank %}
<li>
  <a href="{{ settings.social_instagram_link | escape }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Instagram' }}">
    {% include 'icon-instagram' %}
    <span class="icon__fallback-text">Instagram</span>
  </a>
</li>
{% endif %}
```

CSS for both general icons and social icons:

```
/*================ #Icons ================*/
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  .no-svg & {
  display: none;
  }
}

.icon--wide {
  width: 40px;
}

.icon__fallback-text {
@extend .visually-hidden;

  .no-svg & {
    position: static !important;
    overflow: inherit;
    clip: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

svg.icon:not(.icon--full-color),
symbol.icon:not(.icon--full-color) {
circle,
ellipse,
g,
line,
path,
polygon,
polyline,
rect {
  fill: inherit;
  stroke: inherit;
  }
}

.social-icons .icon {
    fill: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

This is how it looks on Chrome Desktop and Android:

[image]

This is how it looks on iOS (Safari and Chrome):

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the styles of '.icon' and also the HTML?

Comment: @Azu thanks for getting back, I updated the post to include the CSS of .icon and the HTML for the Instagram icon

Comment: only from this code I cannot say what the problem is. In the images you have two icons, however there is only one in your code. Do you have this live somewhere so I can have a look?

Comment: Maybe that's not a problem with overflow, why do you have a ``border-radius: 25px;`` on ``.social-icons .icon`` ?

Comment: @Camille thanks for getting back, it is so that the border around the icons specifically the icons for social media are round.